# Changing size of Google map view in iOS

Tags: ios, google-maps

I want to have a view where 1/2 is google map and 1/2 is text (Listings etc)

But the default map view takes over full screen of view. I haven't seen any docs that mention view sizes etc.

Comment: I found this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17754975/29505

Answer (score 1):

When you choose your `MapKit View` in your storyboard (or xib file), you can rezise it. Like you would do with almost any other component (`UIView`, `UITextView`, ...)

Here is an example :

[image: Example]

I hope it helped. If it didn't, please add some more details to your problem.

Comment: I tried that. But I get an exception that it can't find mksmapview

Comment: In your view controller, you have to : `import MapKit`, create and link an IBOutlet for your map : `@IBOutlet var mapView: MKMapView!`.

Comment: actually http://stackoverflow.com/a/17754975/29505 helped me sort it out. Thanks.