# Marker not locating in google map in subview IOS SWIFT

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps

Hello i was trying to put map in subview but when i put google map in sub view it doesn't work marker and GPS Coordinates don't work

-With Sub View
[image: With Sub View]

-Without Sub View
[image: Without Sub View]

-SWIFT CODE

```
import UIKit
import GoogleMaps

class HomeViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var mapView: GMSMapView!

    let locationManager = CLLocationManager()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()

                let camera = GMSCameraPosition.cameraWithLatitude(15.4989, longitude: 73.8278, zoom: 6)
                let mapView = GMSMapView.mapWithFrame(CGRectZero, camera: camera)
                mapView.myLocationEnabled = true
//                self.view = mapView
                self.view.addSubview(mapView)
                let marker = GMSMarker()
                marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(15.4989, 73.8278)
                marker.title = "Panjim"
                marker.snippet = "Near Don Bosco,Alphran Plaza"
                marker.map?.addSubview(mapView)

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: You use `let mapView = GMSMapView.mapWithFrame(CGRectZero, camera: camera)` which will make the `mapView` has zero size. Also, like @mixth suggested, you should use `marker.map = mapView` instead, to add marker to your `mapView`.

Comment: if i do like that it comes out of the view

Comment: check here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15417811/cannot-put-a-google-maps-gmsmapview-in-a-subview-of-main-main-view/48517389#48517389

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Here is the solution to add marker**

```
            let marker = GMSMarker()
            marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(lat, long)
            marker.appearAnimation = kGMSMarkerAnimationPop
            marker.title = "Marker" // Marker title here
            marker.snippet = "Tap the ↱ Navigate button to start navigating."
            marker.infoWindowAnchor = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0)
            marker.icon = UIImage(named: "marker") //Set marker icon here
            marker.map = self.mapView // Mapview here
```

**Animate Camera to position**

```
    let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: 15.4989, longitude: 73.8278, zoom: 17)
    mapView.animate(to: camera)
```

Answer (score 6):

I found the solution. The problem was : i was creating a new map, then was adding a marker to that new map. Then with the new map i was doing nothing.
So here is my Solution :

```
@IBOutlet weak var subviewMap: GMSMapView!

func loadMap() {
        let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: -33.86, longitude: 151.20, zoom: 10.0)
        subviewMap.camera = camera
        let marker = GMSMarker()
        marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: -33.86, longitude: 151.20)
        marker.title = "Sydney"
        marker.snippet = "Australia"
        marker.map = subviewMap
    }
```

And it works.

**NOTE :** Do not forget to Mention your subview as GMSMapView class in IB

Thanks @O-mkar and @mixth for efforts.

Happy Coding :]

Comment: Thank you, I had same problem !

Answer (score 1):

I have my GMSMapView inside another UIView and everything just works fine. The only different line is:

```
marker.map = mapView
```

Comment: i tried that but its not working for sub view  ... it is only working for main view

Comment: @O-mkar the accepted answer doesnt work, i m facing the same issue. Did you find the solution ?

Comment: @SML i have posted a new answer

Answer (score 1):

```
after adding marker you should add some delay with this approach i have added 2 marker with bounds 

DispatchQueue.main.async {
            if self.markerArray.count > 1 {
                var bounds = GMSCoordinateBounds()
                for marker in self.markerArray {
                    marker.map = self.mapView
                    bounds = bounds.includingCoordinate(marker.position)
                }
                self.isMovedTheMap = false
                DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.9, execute: {
                    self.superTopView.fadeOut()
                    let update = GMSCameraUpdate.fit(bounds, withPadding: 80)
                    self.mapView.animate(with: update)
                })
            }
        }
```