# Center Map and Add Marker with Google Map SDK Subview (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps-sdk-ios

I'm having trouble getting a Google Map to center itself and add a marker when it's a subview connected as an IBOutlet.  I have tried to get it work it feels like 20 different ways, but am stuck so would appreciate any help or guidance.

The code setup is pretty straightforward as follows:

```
//Map view outlet
@IBOutlet weak var googleMapView: GMSMapView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

// Google Map View Setup
    let camera = GMSCameraPosition.cameraWithLatitude(-33.86, longitude: 151.20, zoom: 6)
    let mapView = GMSMapView.mapWithFrame(CGRectZero, camera: camera)
    mapView.myLocationEnabled = true

    self.googleMapView = mapView

    let marker = GMSMarker()
    marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(-33.86, 151.20)
    marker.title = "Sydney"
    marker.snippet = "Australia"
    marker.map = mapView
```

I can get it to work if the view is the entire View Controller by changing self.googleMapView to self.view, but I can't figure out how to get it connected properly to the googleMapView outlet.  Thanks!

I tried using the help given for this [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33274718/marker-not-locating-in-google-map-in-subview-ios-swift) but it's not clearly answered because the outlet and the variable are both mapView and I couldn't get it to work.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Well of course after I asked the question to everyone here I had an epiphany and figured it out!  I didn't need to create a new GMSMapView because that was already done with autolayout.  I just needed to access the camera variable of the that GMSMapView Outlet to set the position.

Code below:

```
 // Google Map View Setup
    let camera = GMSCameraPosition.cameraWithLatitude(-33.86, longitude: 151.20, zoom: 6)
    self.googleMapView.myLocationEnabled = true

    self.googleMapView.camera = camera

    let marker = GMSMarker()
    marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(-33.86, 151.20)
    marker.title = "Sydney"
    marker.snippet = "Australia"
    marker.map = googleMapView
```

Comment: I was having the same problem and this made me see the light.. +1

Answer (score 2):

I think your mapView bounds are not setting properly to the view outlet in viewDidLoad() function. So you can set the mapView bounds from 
 func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool).I had faced the same issue that google map is centering on the self.view properly and not centering on custom view bounds.We found the reason that on func viewDidLoad(),we cant get the rectangle bounds of the view properly.

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        googleMapsView = GMSMapView()
        googleMapsView?.frame = mapView.bounds
        googleMapsView?.myLocationEnabled = true
        if let googleMapView = googleMapsView {
            mapView.addSubview(googleMapView)
        }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set marker and re-position in **viewDidAppear()** because your GMSMapView bounds are calculated properly in this function.

Example:

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    // Add Marker
    let marker = GMSMarker()
    marker.title = "Marker Title Here"
    marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(location.latitude, location.longitude)
    marker.map = mapView

    // Center camera to marker position
    mapView.camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withTarget: marker.position, zoom: 15)
}
```