# GMSMapView not showing anything

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps-sdk-ios, gmsmapview

I currently have a UIView in my View Controller which I have changed to a GMSMapView in the Interface Builder, but nothing shows up, as shown in the picture below:

[image]

Here is the code that I am using

```
    let lat = 47.07903
    let long = -122.961283

    let camera = GMSCameraPosition.cameraWithLatitude(lat, longitude: long, zoom: 10)
    let map = GMSMapView.mapWithFrame(CGRectZero, camera: camera)
    map.myLocationEnabled = true
    map.delegate = self
    self.mapView.addSubview(map)

    let marker = GMSMarker()
    marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(lat, long)
    marker.map = self.mapView
```

I have declared `mapView` as such using drag and drop:

```
@IBOutlet var mapView: GMSMapView!
```

Any help here would be much appreciated. I have tried a lot of different things! Thanks!

Comment: Ensure the bundle identifier set in https://console.developers.google.com matches your current app's bundle identifier

Comment: That actually helped, but now I get another issue where the map starts out somewhere in London, even though my marker is being placed correctly

Comment: Please refer to the answer below.

Comment: Try to set frame to the map view in `let map = GMSMapView.mapWithFrame(CGRectZero, camera: camera)`

Comment: check here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15417811/cannot-put-a-google-maps-gmsmapview-in-a-subview-of-main-main-view/48517389#48517389

Answer (score 13):

This worked for me. https://stackoverflow.com/a/47308301/7560912
You probably have not enabled the google maps API. Go to your app-project's dashboard on https://console.developers.google.com and click the "ENABLE APIS AND SERVICES". There, under the MAPS section select "the Google maps sdk for ios" and enable it.

Comment: @ HighAbove . In my case. I created + used valid key, but it has to be enable. By default it is Disable.

Answer (score 8):

As I was facing same problem and i have found some of my mistakes because of that i am facing same issue.

1) Please create your ios app in google map account.

2) enable maps for you app from google map developer site.

3) use ios google services key in your app.

```
GMSPlacesClient.provideAPIKey("API-KEY")
GMSServices.provideAPIKey("API-KEY")
```

4) must be sure that bundle identifier you are providing is should correct spelled.

Above mistakes is giving me issue please check it.

Answer (score 4):

"ENABLE APIS AND SERVICES".
[image]

work for me, you can try it.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you've got a valid API key from Google Dev Console, and it is correctly added to your app.

In your AppDelegate.m on `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` you should have this:

```
[GMSServices provideAPIKey:@"YOUR_API_KEY"];
```

For more details, go through steps 4 and 5 [HERE](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/start#step_4_get_an_api_key)

Comment: check YOUR_API_KEY from the Google API Console.

Answer (score 0):

To update your `mapview` after placing a marker you can set the maps camera to `GMSCameraPostion`. You can read more about `markers` here-> https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/marker#change_the_marker_opacity

```
 let marker = GMSMarker()
 marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(22.3039, 70.8022)
 marker.map = self.mapView
 viewMap.camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withTarget: marker.position, zoom: 13)
```

Answer (score 0):

hey i faced the same issue when only the marker was shown and the google maps wasn't rendering. The solution for me was to make sure **i was entering the right api key in the app delegate and the info.plist**