# Ionic Native Google Maps fails to load on first use on iPad

Tags: ios, google-maps, ipad, core-data, ionic-framework

There's a bug in this app I'm working on that was made using the Ionic Native Google Maps API. When I run it on an iPad (simulator or actual device), the map API fails to load, but *only* when run the first time. On all subsequent loads of the app, it works without any issues. IIRC, the app will hang when loading on an iPad below a certain iOS version.

This bug does not occur on iPhones or *any* Android devices, and I do have the proper API keys in the app's `config.xml`. My only clue to the issue comes from an error message that appeared when I used Safari's Developer interface to inspect the app (certain things redacted for privacy concerns):

`CoreData: annotation:  Failed to load optimized model at path '/Users/(user-name-redacted)/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/EBF1B0A1-87A8-4E14-8C05-73AF1CB05F05/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/5358FE37-CECB-481D-BCFE-ECA309540DE4/(app-name-redacted).app/GoogleMaps.bundle/GMSCacheStorage.momd/StorageWithTileVersionID.omo'`

Again, this error message *only* appears on an iPad when the app is being run for *the first time after installation*. But most users are going to assume an app isn't going to work at all if it doesn't work properly the first time.

If anyone could provide any insight to what's going on and how to fix this, I'd appreciate it. This one issue is keeping my company from putting this app in the Apple Store.

Comment: It seems this is not plugin's bug, Google's SDK bug. Please report to Google Maps issue tracker.

Comment: Also double check your settings https://stackoverflow.com/a/47308301/697856