# Google Maps iOS SDK Failed to load optimized model at path

Tags: ios, core-data, google-maps-sdk-ios

I'm having an error when trying to load Google Map to view in my Swift app.
The error is:

```
CoreData: annotation:  Failed to load optimized model at path
'/Users/matanlevi/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/DA88A5E1-
99A8-4043-A77E-
1F791C86459E/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/BE4BC021-A5BE-43EF-
9562-
00EE138400E1/VacationDealsApp.app/GoogleMaps.bundle/GMSCacheStorage.momd/
StorageWithTileProto.omo'
```

I can see the map in it default state, without camera zooming on my lat and lon and without markers at all.

I read all the posts about this is issue, tried to downgrade the Google Maps version and even reinstall the pod file. I also made a brand new API key, gave him restriction and bundle id and double checked that Map iOS API is enabled.

I'm working on Xcode Version 9.3, iOS 11.3, Swift 4.1.

Comment: Simulator-only warning or device also?

Comment: It comes up in both of them, exactly the same

Comment: Worth asking, did you clean the build or wipe derived data?

Comment: If you mean "clean" and "build" from product menu, yes I did it. if not please explain a bit more, thanks

Comment: The same issue has been solved in [Failed to load optimized model - GoogleMaps SDK IOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47236769/failed-to-load-optimized-model-googlemaps-sdk-ios)

Answer (score 0):

This is a know issue in Google Maps iOS SDK that you can track here:
https://issuetracker.google.com/64504919

It should have been fixed in the v2.7 where the minimum xCode version was set to 9.0.