# GMSMarker not appearing on map

Tags: swift, google-maps

In swift, I want to show a google-map with a marker on it.
here's storyboard image:
[image]

and here's the code

```
        var camera = GMSCameraPosition.cameraWithLatitude(-33.86,
            longitude: 151.20, zoom: 6)

        var mapView = GMSMapView.mapWithFrame(CGRectZero, camera: camera)
        mapView.myLocationEnabled = true

        self.map.camera = camera
        self.map = mapView

        let marker = GMSMarker()
        marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(-33.86, 151.20)
        marker.title = "title"
        marker.snippet = "snippet"
        marker.map = mapView
```

in the line: 'self.map = mapView' if I write 'self.view = mapView' it will work fine and shows me the marker. but I have other views in the page along with mapView and 'self.view = mapView' will hide them. camera goes to the coordniates also. the only problem is that the marker is not appearing.
what should I do? thanks

Comment: Have you tried marker.map = self.map ?

Comment: yes but that didn't work. I also tried to set 'mapView.accessibilityElementsHidden = false'  but it was useless :(

Comment: check here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15417811/cannot-put-a-google-maps-gmsmapview-in-a-subview-of-main-main-view/48517389#48517389

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the problem after hours googling. the key is to use **Container View** inside the mainView and in the containerView initializing the map with these codes:

```
 var camera = GMSCameraPosition.cameraWithLatitude(-33.86,
            longitude: 151.20, zoom: 6)

        var mapView = GMSMapView.mapWithFrame(CGRectZero, camera: camera)
        mapView.myLocationEnabled = true

        self.map.camera = camera
        self.view = mapView

        let marker = GMSMarker()
        marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(-33.86, 151.20)
        marker.title = "title"
        marker.snippet = "snippet"
        marker.map = mapView
```

Comment: as far as I remember, I put a container view on my view, and put the mapview inside the container view and used this code to resolve the problem.